# Is there an extension of the complex plane that is a group under addition and multiplication?

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers

That is, having both $0$ and $1$ as the identity of $+$ and $\cdot$ respectively, and with an inverse for each ($-a$, $a^{-1}$) satisfying all the group laws.

EDIT:

Forming a group *with* $0$.

Comment: I take it you mean that the non-zero elements will form a group under multiplication.  Check out the [quaternions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)

Comment: The field $\mathbb{C}(x)$ of rational functions with complex coefficients satisfies the specified conditions.

Comment: Not of "multiplication" is defined in the usual way.   Then $0*a = 0*b; a\ne b$ and there being no $c$ so that $0*c = 1$ simply make that impossible.  Of course multiplication doesn't *need* to be defined "the usual way".  But then you can do practically anything

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it's not possible to extend the complex numbers with 0 to a nontrivial group under the usual multiplication, because a group satisfies the two-sided [cancellative properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellation_property) so $0\times0 = 1\times0$ would imply $0=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no, in a very strong way. In particular, addition doesn't even enter the picture: the basic way that $0$ interacts multiplicatively with other numbers ruins any hope of producing a group in the way you want.

In $\mathbb{C}$ - or $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q},...$ - $0$ has a special property: it is an **annihilator** for multiplication, that is, $x\cdot 0=0\cdot x=0$ for all $x$. This means in particular that in all these number systems, **multiplication is not cancellative**: $xz=yz$ does not in general imply $x=y$ (take $z=0$). *(OK fine, this is specifically "right cancellability," but the point stands.)*

The relevance of this is that in a group, the group operation is always cancellative. This is an immediate consequence of the existence of inverses and of associativity: if $xz=yz$ then $(xz)z^{-1}=(yz)z^{-1}$; but by associativity this means $x(zz^{-1})=y(zz^{-1})$, which in turn gives $x=y$. So no non-cancellable operation can be a group operation.

*Side note: cancellativity in fact means that for every group $(G,*)$ and every $g\in G$, the map $Mult_g:G\rightarrow G:h\mapsto gh$ is a permutation of $G$. In particular, **every group can be thought of as a subgroup of the group of all permutations of some set**, namely itself! This is [Cayley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem), and also an important example of the concept of [group actions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action_(mathematics)) (which if I recall correctly actually preceded the abstract notion of a group).*

In particular, there's no way to extend $\mathbb{C}$ *(or $\mathbb{R}$, or ...)* to get a group under multiplication without changing the way multiplication works on $0$ even for "original" numbers.